# Compare selective cells of two rows and calculate deviation using macros in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am pretty new to macros. Just need to do this small task at work.
Overview: I am running two different recipes/programs to generate data.

[image]

Every alternate row is a reading generated from different recipe. I want to compare the last two rows in the same sheet. If the values have a standard deviation of more than 0.5, I need to report or change the colors of the cells. How do I do that?

I wrote the following but it did not work for me:

```
Sub checkit()
Row1length = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For i = 1 To Row1length
    If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(7, i).Value <> Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(8, i) Then
        Match = False
            Exit For
    End If
Next

If Match = True Then
    Debug.Print "match"
Else
    Debug.Print "not match"
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to compare. `Row1length` and `Row2length` are both set to the same thing. And, in the actual comparison test, you are referencing `Cells(1, i)` which would work with only the first row in two different worksheets. Please give at least one specific example so that we can understand better what you're trying to do.

Comment: Hi Pat, thanks for responding. I should have been more clear. I want to compare the last two rows in the same sheet. When I compare I want to check if the values have a standard deviation of more than 0.5. If it does than report it or turn it into some color.

Comment: I replicated your code and it worked fine for me. The only thing that I did differently was to initialize the boolean prior to the loop: `Match = True`.

Answer (score 0):

This code will loop through all the rows in the sheet and compare the first with the second, marking cells which have different values.

```
Sub CheckIt()

    Const FirstDataRow As Long = 2          ' change as required

    Dim Rl As Long, Cl As Long
    Dim R As Long, C As Long

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")               ' change the sheet name
        Rl = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Cl = .Cells(FirstDataRow, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        For R = FirstDataRow To Rl Step 2
            For C = 1 To Cl
                If (.Cells(R, C).Value) <> (Cells(R + 1, C).Value) Then
                    Range(.Cells(R, C), Cells(R + 1, C)).Interior.Color = vbYellow
                End If
            Next C
        Next R
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks variatus. That worked perfectly!
I need to iterate through each column and calculate Std Deviation for all the values in that column. How do I go about that?

Comment: The fastest way is to accept the answer which you received and start a new thread with your new question.